# Sanitize form input

Tags: form, validation, filtering

I'm trying to sanitize form input values in my plugin. 
Yii2 framework provides the following validation method:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#filter

It says that it applies a filter on the input value and assigns it back to the attribute being validated.

However when the entry is saved, I still can see unescaped characters. 
Maybe someone knows why it's not working?

My code looks like this: 
 Plugin.php

```
 Event::on(
        SaveController::class,
        SaveController::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ENTRY,
        function(SaveEvent $event) {
           ...
           $response = Plugin::getInstance()->formValidator->validate($event->entry);
           if(!$response['success']){
             $event->isValid = false;
             $event->entry>addErrors($response['errors']);
           }
        }
```

FormValidator.php

```
public function validate(Entry $entry)
{
    $model = new DynamicModel(
        [
            'firstName' => $entry->firstName,
            'lastName' => $entry->lastName,
            'companyName' => $entry->companyName,
            'email' => $entry->emailAddress,
            'phone' => $entry->phoneNumber,
            'comment' => $entry->comment
        ]
    );

    if(!$model
       ...
        ->addRule(['firstName', 'lastName', 'companyName', 'email', 'phone', 'comment'], 'filter', ['filter' => [$this, 'sanitizeInput']])
      ...
        ->validate()) {

        return [
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $model->getErrors(),
        ];
    }

    return [
        'success' => true,
        'errors' => [],
    ];
}

public function sanitizeInput($value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Never used the filter validation method before, but looking at the docs, should it be `..., 'filter', 'filter' => [$this, 'sanitizeInput'])` ?